# spring rmi @autowired return null

Tags: spring, servlets, rmi, autowired

I am getting a NULL pointer exception on a @autowired object within a RMI service. 
I have created a simple (I think) service to be invoked from a client through RMI. The code is as

```
package com.edvs.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import com.edvs.dao.HostStatusDao;

@Controller
public class HeartbeatImpl implements Heartbeat {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7502560843009449650L;

  @Autowired
  private HostStatusDao hs;

  @Override
  public int update(String hostSequenceNumber) {
    int cnt = hs.update(hostSequenceNumber);
    return cnt;
  }

}//End of file HeartbeatImpl.java.
```

The heartbeat-servlet.xml code is as follows:

```
<bean id="heartbeatBean" class="com.edvs.service.HeartbeatImpl">
  <!-- Nothing here for now. -->
 </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
 <!-- does not necessarily have to be the same name as the bean to be exported -->
 <property name="serviceName" value="Heartbeat"/>
 <property name="service" ref="heartbeatBean"/>
 <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.edvs.service.Heartbeat"/>
 <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
 <property name="registryPort" value="1199"/>
</bean>
```

My WebConfiguration file that specifies the component scan follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.edvs.controller","com.edvs.service" })
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

My HeartbeatImpl.java is within the package com.edvs.service so it should be scanned and the @autowired HostStatusDao should be instantiated but it is not. The property hs is NULL which produces the NULL exception.

I have many controllers in this system that use the exact same @Autowired technique and they work fine. The objects are instantiated. I suspect that this class is failing because of the Bean definition in the heartbeat-servlet.xml file. I am really at a loss here to solve the problem. I must be missing something that is preventing the scanner that catches the @Autowired to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I wasted anybody's time but I think I found the answer in the great cloud. I added the interface ApplicationContextAware like this.

```
public class HeartbeatImpl implements Heartbeat, ApplicationContextAware {
```

This required the method setApplicationContext. Within that method I instantiate my property hs.

```
    @Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
  throws BeansException {
  hs = (HostStatusDao) ctx.getBean("HostStatusDao");

}
```

I hope this helps others because it took me all day to figure this out.